# IIS file download

Tags: iis, download

I've created a new web site in IIS on my machine for testing purposes. Beneath the root I have a folder called documents where I have a bunch of pdf's that should be downloadable. However, when I hit the URL localhost:54510/documents/file.pdf I get a 404 error (Chrome, IE and Firefox).

I've added IIS_IUSRS permissions for the specified folders and the service is running since I can access my ASPNET WebApi - localhost:54510/api/whatever-service-function.

I can't grasp my head around what causes this.

PDF is specified in MIME-types as Application/pdf.

Another thing is, when I add the documents folder as a virtual directory in the Default web site then it works to download it from localhost:80/documents/file.pdf.

I have also tried to add the documents folder as a virtual directory in my web-site and set my local user as the authenticator to see if it had anything to do with permission.

I'm running on IIS 10.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How do you download your file? Via url? or use response?

Comment: When I wrote this, URL, but I ended up making another service call, so now i'm returning a FileResult and it works like a charm.

Comment: So...it's no question now?